# geom_histogram scale percentages by bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this code that produces a graph with many bins for each ticket price where the y-axis is the number of observations and the fill shows me the number of passengers that survived and those that didn't.

```
ggplot(train, aes(x = Avg.Fare.y, fill = Survived)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

But what I really want is a graph that scales each bin so that I can see the percentages of the fill, instead of the count. So something like this:[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV8fu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @JakeKaupp answer works, it's possible to achieve the result without performing the summary calculations outside `ggplot`. Here is an alternative using `geom_bar` (that uses `stat = 'count'` by default) and `position = 'fill'`:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- titanic::titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(fare_bin = cut(Fare, quantile(Fare), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)) 

ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = fare_bin, fill = factor(Survived) ), position = 'fill')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Advice for next time: provide a sample of your data to help us help you.

I would definitely summarize the data outside of plotting, then use `geom_col(position = "stack")` to achieve what you want.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- titanic::titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(fare_bin = cut(Fare, quantile(Fare), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
  count(Survived, fare_bin) %>% 
  group_by(fare_bin) %>% 
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)) 

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = fare_bin, y = percent, fill = factor(Survived))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I tweaked the quantile to breaks = seq(1, lenght, by 2) to get more groups.

PS. Yeah, I should've mentioned it's for the Titanic practice competition from Kaggle...